# Unable to loop over array in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of arrays which looks like this:

```
   var data =  [
      [
        -9814184.757,
        5130582.574600004
      ],
      [
        -9814152.5879,
        5130624.636799999
      ],
      [
        -9814147.7353,
        5130632.882600002
      ]
    ]
```

Now when I try to map it into an object like

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    for (b = 0; b < 1; ++b) {
        var point = new Point(data[i][b],data[i][b]);
    }
}
console.log(point);
```

I am getting `undefined` for x and y in the object

> {type: "point", x: **undefined**, y: **undefined**, spatialReference: {…}}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the inner loop. What are you wanting to do with the new Point?

Comment: Are the inner arrays coordinates (x, y)? Do you want to pass each (x, y) to the `new Point`?

Comment: You are actually assigning the inner arrays to the `x` as well as `y` properties.. Remove the inner for-loop and pass `data[i][0]` / `data[i][1]` to `x`/`y`. Also it would be helpful if you would show us how `Point()` is implemented

Comment: I did but still the X Y values are empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let point = new Point(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
    console.log(point);
}
```

Loop through the array called data in your case. For each of the inner arrays read the first item and assign it to x value and the second item to y value

Comment: Can you provide more code for the Point constructor?

Comment: this is actually ArcGIS API https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/point-amd.html

Comment: The documentation specifies that you need SpatialReference appart from the coordinates x and y. Also where are you using the new object point, outside the loop?

Comment: Give it a try even with this piece of code: let point = new Point(data[i])

Answer (score 2):

Quick and simple:

```
points = data.map(([x, y]) => new Point(x, y));
```